# Getting the ran processes with windows 7 APIs in C++

Tags: c++, api

I'm trying to write a program that I have to know what processes are ran.
Then how could I know what processes are recently ran ?

I write the program in Windows 7 and with visual c++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477097/get-full-running-process-list-visual-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has an [enumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and even gives an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of how to enumerate all processes.